Need help identify Sci-Fi channel TV show/Movie
I am fairly certain I saw this on the Sci-Fi channel, let's say 7/8 years ago.
I remember one scene vividly:
A bunch of people were on a plane/spaceship of sorts and they needed to fly through some phenomenon that would kill anyone who was awake when flying through it.  I think two people were in the pilot chairs and one of the two volunteered to fly through it.  Everyone else fell asleep (the pilot seeming to do so mere seconds before flying through the anomaly) while the other pilot flew the ship/plane through.  I remember it showed bright flashes, etc. and the awake pilot was saying stuff like "It's Beautiful!".  
That's all I remember.  Hopefully it is enough! I can't seem to remember much else.  I would guess the awake pilot was ~30-40 years old and the other pilot was ~50-60.  Maybe a dozen others on the ship?
Feels like it was a movie, but it could have been a TV episode.

There is a Star trek:voyager Episode with the same story, called "One".only sevenofnine and the doctor are awake while flying some weeks through a nebula, rest of crew is put to sleep because otherwise they would be harmed

They definitely weren't "put to sleep", they all fell asleep on their own accord.  I also am close to positive it wasn't weeks long, but rather minutes.

shakes angry fist @walt

@cde +1, anyway. ;)

@Walt - just because this has the same answer as that thread doesn't mean it is a duplicate question, can you unmark it as so please?

@DominicG. I know, but the last part of the old question describes almost exactly what you have. When the questions have strong similarities and have the same answer, I consider them duplicates. (I agree that your question's a good one, though, which is why I upvoted it)

@DominicG. it's just M&TV, and generally SE policy on identification questions for the same material being marked as dupe. It in no way is held against you.

The Langoliers. It was a 2 part mini-series based on the eponymous short story by Stephan King. It was released in 1995 on SciFi, which loves to replay the golden oldie movies.
They had to be asleep to pass through the time vortex a minute into the past, and then again a minute into the future. The one that said "OMG, It's So Beautiful" was Nick, who pulled a heroic sacrifice in order to pilot the plane while the others slept and pass through the vortex alive. It's nearly 2 hours 45 minutes in:



From the Novel's wiki:

On a cross-country red-eye flight from Los Angeles to Boston, ten passengers awaken to find that the crew and most of their fellow passengers have disappeared, leaving the airliner under the control of the autopilot. They realize that only those who were sleeping are now left on the plane. Off-duty airline pilot Brian Engle takes control from the autopilot and lands the plane in Bangor, Maine despite protests from irritable Craig Toomy.
Upon arrival, they find the airport abandoned with no signs of life. Hearing an approaching sound like radio static, the group agrees to leave before it arrives. Based on the belief that they have flown through a "time rip" into the past and that flying back into the rip will return them to their own time, the passengers work together to refuel the plane as the noise gets louder. Having lost touch with reality, Craig believes the others to be manifestations of the Langoliers, monsters he feared as a child that go after those who are lazy and waste time. He stabs Dinah, a young blind girl with psychic powers, and kills Don Gaffey, before being subdued. Dinah insists that Craig must not be killed as the group needs him alive.

From the mini-series' wiki:

They locate the time rip and attempt to fly through it, but at the last minute Bob realizes they were all asleep when they passed through, so passing through awake would kill them. Nick warns Brian, who turns away at the last second. They decide they can reduce the pressure of the cabin to induce unconsciousness, but one of them would have to stay awake to restore the pressure to normal. Nick decides to sacrifice himself and convinces Laurel, with whom he has fallen in love, to go to his estranged father in London and inform him he had decided to quit his career as a hit man. After everyone falls asleep, Nick flies into the rift and vanishes, leaving only his wristwatch behind.


As a note, the passengers were naturally asleep on the way into the past but were put to sleep due to low cabin pressure on the way back into the present... I note this because the OP in a comment seems certain that the falling asleep was natural and not forced.

@Catija I took that to mean they weren't given a sedative/injected/chloroform ragged to sleep. Oxygen deprivation looks natural. And OPs lack of details after a few years. But all the other details are there.

Very good pickup.  I was thinking "put to sleep" in terms of a forceful way, whereas the cabin pressure seemed natural to a degree.
